# jSerialComm: failed to open port (Arduino Mega 2560)

Tags: java, arduino, port

i am working on a project in internship and i have some issues for trying to cummunicate a Java Programme to a Arduino Mega 2560 while using the librairie jSerialComm.
I use the usb cable to connect the arduino.

Here the things, I send the data to the card by the port: /dev/cu.usbmodem1411 so i put this portdescription in the method: `SerialPort.getCommPort("/dev/cu.usbmodem1411");` but everytime i use the method: `sp.openPort()` i can't open the port...

Here is my code in the Java part and the Arduino part.

Java programme:

```
package server;

import cheque.Cheque;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*; // permet de pouvoir faire du réseau avec java

import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.*;

//javac -cp c:\../../classes:c:\../../classes/com/fazecast/jSerialComm-2.6.2.jar -d ../../classes Serveur_trie.java
//java -cp .:c:\../../classes:c:\../../classes/com/fazecast/jSerialComm-2.6.2.jar server.Serveur_trie

// ATTENTION: activer XAMPP avant de lancer le serveur pour que les clients se connectent

public class Serveur_trie extends Thread
{
    String name; // nom du client connecté au thread serveur
    Socket clientSocket;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    private static HashMap<String, Serveur_trie> tableau_nom = new HashMap<String, Serveur_trie>(); // stocke les noms d'utilisateurs dans un tableau



    private int algorithme_trie(int num_donnee) // permet de trouver la case pour trier le cheque
    {
        return num_donnee;
    }

    private void display_port()
    {
        SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        for (int i = 0; i < ports.length; i++) 
        {
        System.out.println(ports[i].getSystemPortName());
        }
    }

    private void envoie_donnee_arduino(Integer num_led) throws Exception 
    // permet d'envoyer les données de l'algorithme à la partie Arduino13
    {
        display_port();
        SerialPort sp = SerialPort.getCommPort("/dev/cu.usbmodem1411"); // port de la carte aruino Mega 2650

        sp.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, 0); // default connection settings for Arduino
        sp.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0, 0); // block until bytes can be written

        if (sp.openPort()) //ouvre le port en question en mode lecture et écriture
        {
            System.out.println("Port is open");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to open port");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println(num_led.byteValue());
        sp.getOutputStream().write(num_led.byteValue()); // écrit les données en BYTE du serveur vers le port
        sp.getOutputStream().flush(); // permet de forcet l'écriture des donnés du buffer
        Thread.sleep(1000);      

        if (sp.closePort()) //ferme le port en question en mode lecture et écriture
        {
            System.out.println("Port is closed :)");
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to close port :(");
            return;

        }

    }

    public void run() // fonction du thread
    {

        try (
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        )
        {
            Object o = in.readObject();
            if (o instanceof Cheque)
            {
                Cheque cheque = (Cheque) o;
                System.out.println("info: " + cheque.get_Num_case());
                envoie_donnee_arduino(algorithme_trie(cheque.get_Num_case()));
            }
           /* else 
            if(o instanceof String) 
            {
                if( ((String) o).equals("BYE") )
                {
                    break;
                }
            }*/
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception while closing connection!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }

    public Serveur_trie(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException // a executer dans un autre ordinateur
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Bienvenue au serveur, Veillez saisir...");
        System.out.println("Votre numéro de port >"); // ATTENTION, si vous avez pas le root privilege alors prenez un numéro de port > 1024
        int num_port = scanner.nextInt(); // on enregistre le numéro du

        try (
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(num_port); // on crée l'application serveur sur un port
        )
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Serveur_trie server = new Serveur_trie(serverSocket.accept()); // on attend et accepte la demande de connexion d'un client
                System.out.println("Client connecté");
                server.start();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port " + num_port);
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("fermeture du serveur");
        scanner.close();

    }
}
```

Arduino programm:

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int ref_pin = 1;

void all_led(int dep_led)
{
  for (int i = ref_pin; i < ref_pin + 15 ; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(i,LOW);
  }
  delay(1000);

  for (int i = ref_pin; i < ref_pin + 15 ; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(i,HIGH);
  }
  delay(1000);
}


void setup() 
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  for (int i = ref_pin; i < 16 ; i++)
  {
    pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
  }

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) 
  {
    Serial.print("Wait");
    ; // wait for serial port to connect.
  }
  //pinMode(11,OUTPUT);

  for (int i = ref_pin; i < ref_pin + 15 ; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(i,HIGH);
  }
  Serial.print("Pin ready!");
}

void loop() 
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  if (Serial.available() > 0) 
  {    
    byte incomingByte = 0;
    incomingByte = Serial.read(); // read the incoming byte:
    Serial.print(incomingByte);
    if (incomingByte != -1) // -1 means no data is available
    {

    }
  }

  //all_led(ref_pin);
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you write a Java program that will open some available port - that will help prove that your Java side is OK. Second, in the loop in `setup` that is checking whether `Serial` is up and running, you print to `Serial`! That seems like a bad idea to me... If `Serial` is not there yet, how can we print to it? Could that cause the Arduino to hang, so that Java never sees it? I don't know. Third, your two `ref_pin` loops can be combined. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i can open the port and i have made some change in the arduino code but i can't figure at how to send data to the arduino. Everytime i try to this, it doens't register the data i send but other data

Comment: * it doens't register the data i send but other data* - so it receives something but not what you sent? Different baud rates? Do you have the Arduino IDE open? or its serial monitory?  They might cause the port to be busy. Sorry, just really guessing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever i want to work with serial ports, i always first check that i could define my ports correctly before writing data to it.
In your code, you get ports 2 times, I suggest to use the example of JSerialComm defining the ports. Then use the one it is finding.

try this first to see if you can find your ports first.

```
System.out.println("\nUsing Library Version v" + SerialPort.getVersion());
    SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
    System.out.println("\nAvailable Ports:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < ports.length; ++i)
        System.out.println("   [" + i + "] " + ports[i].getSystemPortName() + ": " + ports[i].getDescriptivePortName() + " - " + ports[i].getPortDescription());
    SerialPort ubxPort = ports[i]; // instead of i use the port that is available.
```

This is from JSerialComm example , first by using this, defining the ports into an array, then printing it, then, choose the one I want(if there are more than one port in your system) 
After you make sure defining your ports correctly then you can write or read data or configure it easily.

Also I recommend using “serial monitor” softwares , that you can see what data you are transferring to the port and if your data is correct.
I hope this could help.